# eCryptfs: what if I remove ~/.ecryptfs

Tags: ecryptfs

I'm learning how to use eCryptfs: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs

I get things as below from the link:

> This is used to derive the actual file encryption master key. Thus,
>   you should not enter a custom one unless you know what you are doing -
>   instead press Enter to let it auto-generate a secure random one. It
>   will be encrypted using the login passphrase and stored in this
>   encrypted form in ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase. Later it will
>   automatically be decrypted ("unwrapped") again in RAM when needed, so
>   you never have to enter it manually. Make sure this file does not get
>   lost, otherwise you can never access your encrypted folder again!

So I did a simple test:

```
mkdir -p ~/test
mount -t ecryptfs ~/test ~/test
cd ~/test && vim data
umount -t ecryptfs ~/test
```

For now, I did get an encrypted file, which means that `~/test/data` was unreadable.
Of course, if I mount it again, I can read it.

Now, I delete `~/.ecryptfs`: `sudo rm -rf ~/.ecryptfs`.
Then I try to mount it: `sudo mount -t ecryptfs ~/test ~/test`

To my surprise, I can still mount it and read the `~/test/data`.

Now I'm confused. I thought I could move `~/.encryptfs` into some USB to keep my secret data secure. But it doesn't seem to work because I can still mount it even if I delete `~/.encryptfs`. Am I doing something wrong?

If I'm right, the whole security is based on ONLY one thing: the login passphrase. In this case, what is the wrapped-passphrase? why is it so important? why does it say " Make sure this file does not get lost, otherwise you can never access your encrypted folder again!"?

Comment: Did you reboot the system in between? The above text is also telling you that it will be kept in RAM.

Comment: @Seth  Yes, I rebooted.

Comment: I don't have a system to write a post on, but `keyctl show`.

Comment: @grawity  Sorry but what do you mean? I should `keyctl unlink` manually after `umount`?

Comment: @grawity   Well, I just `keyctl unlink` all I can but I can still mount it only if I type login passphrase, which means that I CAN get decrypt it without `~/.encryptfs`.